# Can I pass a loop in RecyclerViews customAdapter-onBindViewHolder()?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have an `arrayList` of customClass named as mainList. It has two sub-arrayLists of customClass, say sub1 and sub2. when my `adapteronBindViewHolder()` reads the mainList, it works good for sub1 but at start of sub2, it shows first record multiple times.
mainList position for lastItem of sub1 is 3.
mainList position for first item of sub2 is 4 and sub2 position is at 0;

Used `recyclerview` with custom arraylist (mainList).
Consider mainList is already filled.
Help needed in `onBindViewHolder().`

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final CustomMainListAdapter.mainHolder mainHolder= (CustomMainListAdapter.mainHolder) holder;

    if (mainList.get(position).getArrayType().equals("sub1")) {
        if (mainList.get(position).getsub1Array() != null) {
            if (mainList.get(position).getsub1Array().size() > 0) {

                mainHolder.text_mainTitle.setText(mainList.get(position).getsub1Array().get(position).getsub1Title());
                mainHolder.text_mainsubTitle.setText(mainList.get(position).getsub1Array().get(position).getsub1Product());
                mainHolder.text_main_contact.setText(mainList.get(position).getsub1Array().get(position).getsub1phoneNumber());

            }
        }
    }
    else {

        if (mainList.get(position).getsub2Array() != null) {
            if (mainList.get(position).getsub2Array().size() > 0) {
                Log.e("tag","main-adapter size: "+mainList.get(position).getsub2Array().size());

                for(int i=0;i<mainList.get(position).getsub2Array()().size();i++ ){
                    mainHolder.text_mainTitle.setText(mainList.get(position).getsub2Array()().get(i).getName());
                    mainHolder.text_mainsubTitle.setText(mainList.get(position).getsub2Array()().get(i).getProductTask());
                    mainHolder.text_main_contact.setText(mainList.get(position).getsub2Array()().get(i).getContact());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Expected output should be all records of sub1 will be displayed first and then sub2 records from mainList.

Comment: Keep in mind that `onBindViewHolder` will be called against each item. So you have to sort your `mainList` if necessary as far my understanding of what you posted.

Answer (score 0):

You have to filter and create the main list before set adapter to your recycler view means you have to remove your if condition code from `onBindViewHolder` and put in your main class where you set the adapter of your list

After Filtering the main list you passed only one list to the adapter which will have records of a first sub1 array and then sub2 array vice-versa

This will increase your recycler view performance and solved your problem also.